# Ruby on Rails: Cant download new gems (Name or service not known)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

For some reason, I can't add new gems (which haven't been donwloaded/used before) to my system. When I run `bundle install` after adding them to the `Gemfile`, I get errors like this:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:180:in `fetch_path': SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/google_places_autocomplete-0.0.2.gemspec.rz) (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError) from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:106:in `fetch_spec'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/remote_specification.rb:47:in `_remote_specification'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/remote_specification.rb:53:in `method_missing'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:101:in `__dependencies'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:98:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:98:in `__dependencies'
....
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/bundle:19
```

This just happened out of the blue. All the gems I'm trying are from the official `rubygems.org` website. It's always the same exact error (just with the gem name changed in the URL on the first line). If I run `bundle install` without adding any new gems, it works fine.

Does anyone have any insight on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you post before and after `Gemfile`?

Comment: @user482594
`gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.3.3', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'devise'
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
gem 'google_places'
#gem 'google_places_autocomplete' `
This is the before gemfile. In the after, I simply uncomment the last line.

Comment: This looks like a network error. Are you sure rubygems.org is reachable from your location?

Comment: Has this same error. Looks like re-fetching fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@eugen Thank you. Yes rubygems.org was reachable, but my DNS servers were configured incorrectly. I added an openDNS server (8.8.8.8) to my DNS servers in my network preferences, now it works fine.

Comment: how do you add an openDNS server (8.8.8.8) to your DNS servers in your network preferences?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error and removed my Gemfile.lock. This fixed it. It might not be acceptable for everyone, but it worked in my situation.

Comment: Worked for me too when jekyll stopped working. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Has this same error.  Looks like re-fetching fixed it.

Comment: what do you mean by re-fetching exactly?